# Elastic search query to return top 3 of each categories

Tags: elasticsearch, search, types

I want to write an elastic query where it should return top 3 books of 2 authors say Sidney Sheldon and John Gresham.

The document contains the fields id, title, author, no_copies_sold, release_Date ...

I want to accomplish this in single query instead of querying for 2 times each for Sidney Sheldon and John Gresham.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter on author to target only documents you want.
After aggregate by author, then take the top 3 no_copies_sold (= top_book) and ask for the title (add others fields if you need in the query).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "author": [
        "Sidney Sheldon",
        "John Gresham"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "author_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "no_copies_sold": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": [
              "title"
            ],
            "size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```